# Does powershell use CLR?

Tags: windows-7, powershell-3.0

I know that powershell was built on top of .net. So does that mean it uses CLR? If yes, does that mean CLR works as an interpreter, converting directly from *.ps1 into machine code?

Comment: The CLR isn't an interpreter.

Comment: actually, per wikipedia, the CLR is the VM, which makes it the interpreter by virtue of the fact that it performs JIT compilation to machine code. in a hybrid complier/runtime like .net, neither term compiler nor interpreter fit in the purest sense of their definitions, but since its JIT, interpreter is a perfectly acceptable term. and OP, yes PS uses the CLR for .net features, but not for builtin commands. it uses external executables and functionality built into powershell that uses windows API functions.